Rolling mean, timedelta offset, min_periods, and center
I would like an annual rolling window that is centered, and where we have missings when the window is calculated over missing data -- at the start and end of the time series, something like:
test.head(20)
Out[39]: 
                 foo
month               
2016-08-01       NaN
2016-09-01       NaN
2016-10-01       NaN
2016-11-01       NaN
2016-12-01       NaN
2017-01-01 =mean(2016-08-01 to 2016-07-01)
2017-02-01 =mean(2016-09-01 to 2016-08-01)
2017-03-01 =mean(2016-10-01 to 2016-09-01)

(because its an annual average with monthly data, I don't particularly care whether its 6 months before, and 5 months after, or 5 before and 6 after (or even 6 and 6).
Here are the first rows of my test data:
test.head(20)
Out[39]: 
                 foo
month               
2016-08-01 -0.105854
2016-09-01 -0.120718
2016-10-01 -0.129150
2016-11-01 -0.114559
2016-12-01 -0.135669
2017-01-01 -0.140636
2017-02-01 -0.094412
2017-03-01 -0.139349
2017-04-01 -0.099603
2017-05-01 -0.076229
2017-06-01 -0.098049
2017-07-01 -0.108535
2017-08-01 -0.037598
2017-09-01 -0.181011
2017-10-01 -0.121715
2017-11-01 -0.089486
2017-12-01 -0.132886
2018-01-01 -0.063460
2018-02-01 -0.111066
2018-03-01 -0.130275

A standard rolling mean works well
test.rolling('365D').mean()
Out[41]: 
                 foo
month               
2016-08-01 -0.105854
2016-09-01 -0.113286
2016-10-01 -0.118574
2016-11-01 -0.117570
2016-12-01 -0.121190

, also when I specify min_periods:
test.rolling('365D', min_periods=3).mean()
Out[45]: 
                 foo
month               
2016-08-01       NaN
2016-09-01       NaN
2016-10-01 -0.118574
2016-11-01 -0.117570
2016-12-01 -0.121190

But when I specify center=True, behold:
test.rolling('365D', min_periods=3, center=True).mean()
Out[46]: 
                 foo
month               
2016-08-01 -0.124431
2016-09-01 -0.122543
2016-10-01 -0.119995
2016-11-01 -0.115618
2016-12-01 -0.114021

What am I missing?

What would be your expected output?

@mozway I hope this clarified?

Do you have all months available? If yes, use test.rolling('365D', min_periods=12, center=True).mean(). If not, please clarify what should happen in this case.

Code
# before 6 + after 5

out1 = test.rolling(12, center=True).mean()

# before 5 + after 6

out2 = test.rolling('365D', min_periods=12, center=True).mean()

With center=True, half of them are already over 3, setting min_periods=3 is meaningless.

One option could be to ensure having a monthly frequency (with asfreq) and to use 12 periods (not '365D'):
test.asfreq('MS').rolling(12, center=True).mean()

Output:
                 foo
month               
2016-08-01       NaN
2016-09-01       NaN
2016-10-01       NaN
2016-11-01       NaN
2016-12-01       NaN
2017-01-01       NaN
2017-02-01 -0.113564
2017-03-01 -0.107876
2017-04-01 -0.112900
2017-05-01 -0.112280
2017-06-01 -0.110191
2017-07-01 -0.109959
2017-08-01 -0.103528
2017-09-01 -0.104916
2017-10-01 -0.104159
2017-11-01       NaN
2017-12-01       NaN
2018-01-01       NaN
2018-02-01       NaN
2018-03-01       NaN

